# Display data with hasMany relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a list which is displayed which has a hasMany relationship. I'm not having trouble displaying the initial list, but I would like to display data from a second JSON when a link in the item is clicked.

Here are my models:

```
    App.TemplateInstance = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr(),
      template_instances_audiences: DS.hasMany("TemplateInstanceAudience", {async:true})
    });

    App.TemplateInstanceAudience = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr(),
      template_instance: DS.belongsTo("TemplateInstance",{async:true}),
      asset_instances: DS.hasMany("AssetInstance")
    });

    App.AssetInstance = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr(),
      template_instance_audience: DS.belongsTo("TemplateInstanceAudience")
    });
```

I'm using mockjax to simulate making a GET request. As you can see from the mockjax, I have different nested routes displaying different data:

```
$.mockjax({
      url: '/templateInstances/4',
      dataType: 'json',
      responseText: {
        template_instances: {
          id: 1,
          name: "bill",
          links: {
            template_instances_audiences: "/templateInstances/4/audiences"
          }
        }
      }
    });


$.mockjax({
  url: "/templateInstances/4/audiences",
  dataType: "json",
  responseText: {
    template_instance_audiences: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "bar 1",
      template_instance: 1,
      links: {
        asset_instances: "/templateInstances/4/audiences/1/assets"
      }

    },{
      id: 2,
      name: "bar 2",
      template_instance: 1,
      links: {
        asset_instances: "/templateInstances/4/audiences/2/assets"
      }
    }]
  }
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/templateInstances/4/audiences/1/assets",
  dataType: "json",
  responseText: {
    asset_instances: [{
      id: 1,
      asset_id: 1,
      name: "Assets 1",
      template_instance: 1
    },{
      id: 2,
      asset_id: 2,
      name: "Assets 2",
      template_instance: 1
    }]
  }
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/templateInstances/4/audiences/2/assets",
  dataType: "json",
  responseText: {
    asset_instances: [{
      id: 3,
      asset_id: 3,
      name: "Assets 3",
      template_instance: 1
    },{
      id: 4,
      asset_id: 4,
      name: "Assets 4",
      template_instance: 1
    }]
  }
});
```

My template is displaying the items from template instance model.

```
    <ul>
    {{#each item in template_instances_audiences}}
      <li><a href="#" {{action "displayAssets"}}>{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

..and when an item is clicked, the list will appear in

```
  <ul>
{{#each item in asset_instances}}
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

How can I get the links from the assets_instances links property and then display it on the front end? When I do a console.log, I'm unable to get the link in relation to the item.

Hopefully the jsbin will make it a bit clearer: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yebuzi/2/edit

Comment: JSbin doesn't load for me. Anyways, did you tried using `{{link-to}}` instead?

Comment: Just checked the JSbin link in FF and Chrome and it seems fine. I haven't tried **{{link-to}}** because the second list I want to populate is on the same page..